# Is there a Win32 API to copy a fragment of a file on another file?

Tags: file, winapi

I would like to programmatically copy a section of a file on another file. Is there any Win32 API I could use without moving bytes thru my program? Or should I just read from the source file and write on the target?

I know how to do this by reading and writing chunks of bytes, I just wanted to avoid doing it myself if the OS already offers that.

Comment: I don't know why you would expect there to be such a specialized function. It's such a narrow use case that I think it would be absurd for Microsoft to even provide it.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for the answer. I don't think it should exist. I just wanted to know if it existed.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia - while I've not used them myself, I think you could achieve this with memory-mapped files and a simple, single call to `memcpy`. :) Though to be honest,it's likely overkill for your task. You can see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms810613.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx copies a file, not quite what you want though. You can use streams to copy part of a file to a new one.

Comment: Sure, you can use memory mapped files and streams, which are attractive on the surface, but more complex than necessary when you really look into them. Your problem is trivial using nothing more than the standard Win32 file functions.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, it's trivial. But what if you have big files (which I do)? Copying big files using standard functions takes longer than it would if the OS offered some help.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia No matter how you do it, a file copy is a file copy. You have to move the bytes from one place to another, and that _requires_ reading them and then writing them. That's what `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` do, and they do it about as efficiently as it can be done. Any other approach you use will just be a layer on top of `ReadFile/WriteFile`, so I don't know what magic it is you're expecting the OS to provide. If the files are large, then using large buffer sizes will help maximize performance. If you want to make your I/O non-blocking, that can be done too.

Comment: All Win32 functions are entry points into the OS, so I don't understand your thinking that the OS isn't providing "help."

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for your comments. My thinking was that maybe there was some way to transfer bits from one file to another without moving them thru the application's memory space because that consumes some resources (time and buffer space.) If you think my question is stupid or inappropriate, please downvote it and I will likely delete it without further delay. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't think your question is stupid or inappropriate. If I did, I would have already downvoted and wouldn't bother replying to you. What you're asking for can be achieved. Device drivers routinely transfer data without CPU involvement, but doing that requires kernel mode code. Basically, you would have to write a device driver. The benefits would have to be huge to justify the difficulties associated with developing, testing, and distributing a kernel mode driver. So unless you think there is huge benefit at stake here, I'm afraid that `ReadFile/WriteFile` are the best you can do.

Comment: @CareyGregory, this is a very good answer. Would you mind moving it from the comment to the main area? That would allow both of us to put an end to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for can be achieved, bot not easily. Device drivers routinely transfer data without CPU involvement, but doing that requires kernel mode code. Basically, you would have to write a device driver. The benefits would have to be huge to justify the difficulties associated with developing, testing, and distributing a kernel mode driver. So unless you think there is huge benefit at stake here, I'm afraid that ReadFile/WriteFile are the best you can do.